# Layer remove swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, view, layer

This function allows me to save a `UIImageView` called `sticker` containing a `UIImage`.
I paste the layers to 0 and it works correctly. But if I insert 2 or more `UIImageView` called "sticker", I remove the layers only one. I need to remove the layers from each sticker that is inserted or added.

```
    func saveHappyFriend() {
        self.sticker?.xButton.alpha = 0
        self.sticker?.layer.borderWidth = 0
        self.sendSaveStickyProbe()
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.managedView.workbenchView.frame.size, true, 0)
        self.managedView.workbenchView.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)

        if let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() {
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
            self.router.routeToShareScene(from: self, with: image)
        } else {
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you please explain your problem clearly

Comment: I have a view, where I can insert infinite imageView called "sticker", I need to remove the layer to all those present. while with this code I delete the layer I am at the first imageView inserted. @Ruban4Axis

Comment: We can not see any code that is inserting or removing any layers. To remove all subLayers from a `view` you can try `self.view.layer.sublayers?.forEach({ $0.removeFromSuperlayer()})`

Comment: @Kamran strange thing, this way does not change anything. they always remain

Comment: Put breakpoint in `forEach`, see if layers are getting removed or not. As you didn't show any code so i am not sure about retain cycles.